# Webpack - importing from absolute path

Tags: sass, webpack

I have a `scss` file located in `src/app/views/style.scss`.

I also have an image file in `src/app/images/icon.png`.

**I want to do something like this:** (notice the absolute path)

```
background-image: url("/images/icon.png");
```

However, this doesn't work obviously because I need to use a relative path to go up to the parent directory.

This works (a relative path), but is undesirable:

```
background-image: url("../images/ico-add.png");
```

How can I configure Webpack to respect absolute URLs in nested files?

Comment: What's your webpack config? Do you have a base path set for files/this type of file?

Comment: @ssube for images, I have `{
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]'
      }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was having was that when importing one scss file into another that wasn't necessarily in the same directory, I would get issues. So I thought using absolute URLs would solve this issue.

I was able to find a different solution to this problem. Using the [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader), and setting webpack.config.js to use this:

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", 'resolve-url', "sass?sourceMap"]
}
```

Relative paths were now resolved properly depending on the original file the `url(...)` statement was in.

I would still be interested however in a solution to the question of using absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured in css loader:

https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#root-relative-urls

"For urls that start with a /, the default behavior is to not translate them:"

So I assume you want to translate urls start with a /. You can add a root parameter to the css loader.